# Transforming an object hierarchy using Jackson

Tags: jackson

I would like to leverage the Jackson infrastructure to transform an untyped Map/List structure into a POJO hierarchy.
What I need is pretty close to

```
jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(MapHierarchy) followed by
pojoTree = objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode)
```

...except that I need to modify the field names on the fly: the names found in the source Map/List hierarchy are declared as custom annotations on the POJO class.
Here is a complete example:

```
public class Cat
{
   @MapField("attr:col")
   @JsonProperty("color")
   private String _color;
}
```

... and the source Map:

```
{
   "attr:col" -> "black"
}
```

... from which I would like to obtain a Cat instance.

I am sure there has got to be an elegant way to achieve this with the Jackson APIs, but I can't quite figure out how... any suggestions? Obviously I don't want to create a second parallel class hierarchy just to describe the deserialization of the Map through annotations.
An extra bonus would be to be able to transform the Map without going through stringified JSon which I believe is how valueToTree works.